# Sharepoint 2013 - custom page layout looks different (messed up) in Edit/Content Author Mode

Tags: 2013, page-layout, custom

This question is about Sharepoint Custom Page Layout that looks different (messed up) in Edit(Content Author) mode.

What is causing this?

[image: Page in published/checked in mode]

When the page is published or checked in - it looks correct.

[image: Page in Edit Mode/ Content Author Mode]